# What is the grey box on selecting Webform Payment Processor?

Tags: payment-processor, drupal-views

**Specific Issue**
I have a View that contains a Views Block Area as one of its rows. In each of these Views Block Areas I have a Webform that contains a CiviCRM Payment Processor.

I want the Payment Processor that is used to be set on content within the row.

When I set this by Javascript I get a grey box appearing on the screen and disappearing. Google Chrome's Console shows the data is: form?currency=GBP&snippet=4&processor_id=[[index of the selected payment processor]]

My Questions are:

1) What is this for? What does it do?
2) How can I get rid of it / stop it happening?
3) Is there a better way other than javascript to do this? The only other thing I could think of was using views_post_render. That feels like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

**Purpose**
I want to be able to have multiple donation options on the same screen for a crowd funding effort. These options are generated by a View. I am open to having a link instead of a payment form, and definitely open to a better way than using Views Block Areas in rows!

Comment: can you explain a bit more about why you need separate webforms for each payment processor? ie what does this achieve that fails just by offering 'user select' on the PP in a single webform?

Comment: I think you are referring to the jquery blockUI which was enabled on the webform_civicrm payment page recently to prevent submission until the processor has actually loaded all it's fields?

Comment: @MatthewWire If you answer the question with that I'll accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to the jquery blockUI which was enabled on the webform_civicrm payment page recently to prevent submission until the processor has actually loaded all it's fields?